# Serialize and Deserialize using BinaryFormatter between NET Standard and NET Framework

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a class in a .NET Standard 2 class library:

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomObject
{
    public Dictionary<DayOfWeek, decimal> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

I serialize it using a BinaryFormatter in a .NET Core console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        var customObject = new CustomObject { Dictionary = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, decimal> { { DayOfWeek.Friday, 100m } } };

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, customObject);

            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\serializedObject.dat", memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

If I deserialize it in a .NET Framework console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\serializedObject.dat");

        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var customObject = (CustomObject) binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);

            var keyCount = customObject.Dictionary.Keys.Count;

        }
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Unable to load type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.DayOfWeek, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] required for deserialization.'

So I created a custom binder:

```
public class CustomBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (typeName.Equals(
            "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.DayOfWeek, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
        )
        {
            return typeof(Dictionary<DayOfWeek, decimal>);
        }

        return Type.GetType($"{typeName}, {assemblyName}");
    }
}
```

After that, I get the following error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'The object with ID 5 was referenced in a fixup but does not exist.'

So I add another conversion to the serialization binder:

```
public class CustomBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (typeName.Equals(
            "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.DayOfWeek, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
        )
        {
            return typeof(Dictionary<DayOfWeek, decimal>);
        }

        if (typeName.Equals(
            "System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.DayOfWeek, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
        )
        {
            return typeof(KeyValuePair<DayOfWeek, decimal>);
        }

        return Type.GetType($"{typeName}, {assemblyName}");
    }
}
```

And get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Object must implement IConvertible.'

All types passed through the binder are:

```
SharedLib.CustomObject, SharedLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.DayOfWeek, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Collections.Generic.EnumEqualityComparer`1[[System.DayOfWeek, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.DayOfWeek, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.DayOfWeek, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

How can I get this to deserialize?

Comment: I guess this isn't surprising. Microsoft [doesn't recommend using binary seralization with `BinaryFormatter`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23584#issuecomment-325826116) anyway because of security concerns. It is quite trivial to serialize and deserialize using `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader`, which would be portable across frameworks. I would give you a demonstration, but since you specifically mention `BinaryFormatter` it doesn't answer your question.